# Can't load the GKAchievementDescription image with loadImageWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I am working on Game Center for iOS devices using the **sandbox** environment. I am trying to load the **achievement images** I set up in iTunes Connect.

I am using **loadAchievementDescriptionWithConpletionHandler** successfully.

The problem happens when I try to load the image using **loadImageWithCompletionHandler**.

```
[self.description loadImageWithCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
          self.achievementImage = image;
     }
 }];
```

The problem is both the UIImage and the error are nil. 
**It is due to the sandbox environment ?** Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: If you just added the image in iTunes Connect, there is usually a delay until your game can access any new or changed information from the sandbox servers. If the image is there in iTunes Connect, your code should work fine. However, you should handle the error instead of only proceeding if there isn't one for all of these GameKit block callbacks. Even a simple NSLog of the (potential) error description is helpful when debugging.

Comment: Thank you Corbin. Indeed, I am processing the error more than that. However, I was puzzled having both the image and the error nil. I still do as a matter of fact. I will re set my images in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the default achievement view controller and seeing if that loads the images?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. It does not show on the **GKGameCenterViewController**. But now, it seems I can load the images as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can load the image successfully. It looks like my image format was wrong.

I have deleted the achievement and created a new one using a 512x512 72 dpi image.

Using **loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler**. I load all the achievementDescriptions from Game Center. Then, I use **loadImageWithCompletionHandler** to extract the image.

```
[GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (GKAchievementDescription *achievementDescription in descriptions) {
            [self.achievementDescriptionDictionary setObject:achievementDescription
                                                      forKey:achievementDescription.identifier];

            [achievementDescription loadImageWithCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    if (image) {
                        UIImage *achievementimage = image;
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Further testing. It looks like it is sandbox environment issue. The problem comes and goes.